# PHP method chaining: Does the PSR specify arrow alignment?

Tags: php

Is there any strict requirement if chaining should be aligned starting with the class vs. methods only?

> Chaining with only methods being aligned:

```
$this->fooService
    ->doBar()
    ->doBaz();
```

Above example shows the alignment just within methods.

> Chaining with everything being aligned:

```
$this
    ->fooService
    ->doBar()
    ->doBaz();
```

This question is not opinion based as I'm asking about coding standard defined by the PHP community.

Answer (score 4):

The PSR and PSR 2 do not specify anything regarding method chaining from what I have read. PSR concludes that "interline alignment" is intentionally left out