# PSR-12 and method chaining

Tags: php, psr-12

Does PSR-12 establish any kind of restriction with method chaining? Are both options below equally valid according to the standard?

Option 1:

```php
$object->methodA()->methodB()->methodC()->methodD();
```

Option 2:

```php
$object->methodA()
    ->methodB()
    ->methodC()
    ->methodD();
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623909/php-method-chaining-does-the-psr-specify-arrow-alignment but not much on it either.

Comment: It is in fact similar although in my question I specially interested in knowing if multiple methods chained in one line is correct from a PSR-12 perspective.

Comment: Both correct (because it doesnt specify it) but option 1 can easier cause problems with line lengths https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#23-lines. This can be a rule in your own coding standards (additional to psr for example)